# How to interpret economic significance from the regression (OLS) coefficient?

Tags: statistics, regression, coefficients

I have the results from the following regression (pooled OLS with industry and year fixed effects):

`y =0.02 - 0.31*X1 + 0.23*X2 + residual`

Please, correct me if I am wrong with interpreting the economic significance of X1 on y (where the mean value in the sample of X1 is o.55 and standard deviation is 0.1):

One standard deviation increase in X1 (holding all other factors constant) decreases "y" by 0.031 (0.31*0.1) from its mean of 0.22 to 0.189, or 14%.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).